# Error in --commit CMD Change in Docker via command line

Tags: docker, cmd, jar, commit

[image]

I am trying to put a spring boot java .jar file into an Image off openJDK and commit the change to it  in docker but docker command does not seem to work

I am following this article for steps : https://dzone.com/articles/docker-tutorial-for-beginners-with-java-and-spring

What argument is docker expecting which , I did not give in the command

```
docker container commit --change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/mytroubleartifact-0.jar"]' upbeat_brahmagupta a-repo-name-of-choice/some-app-name:tagname2
```

Comment: The image you create this way won't be reproducible.  If there's a significant security issue in the JVM and you need to upgrade the base image, will you remember this exact `docker commit` command in a year?  Better to create a Dockerfile and check it in to your source tree with your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with the apostrophe `'` you should be using apostrophe**s** (in plural - otherwise known as quotation mark**s**) `"`

### This command seems to be working for me

(no changes needed on your behalf):

`docker container commit --change="CMD ['java','-jar','/tmp/mytroubleartifact-0.jar']" upbeat_brahmagupta a-repo-name-of-choice/some-app-name:tagname2`

though I've seen other people using a single apostrophe for me it also didn't work with your situation. [docker docs example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) also didnt work with just copying the `--change` part, with both options (`-c`, `--change`) and with just one of them, only using double qoutes did the trick, not exactly sure why though. (tried replacing names, making them shorter ¯_(ツ)_/¯)

> `docker commit --change='CMD ["apachectl", "-DFOREGROUND"]' -c "EXPOSE 80" c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version4`

[image]

thanks to these posts for the working example:

https://adamtheautomator.com/docker-commit/
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E75728/html/ch04s18.html

Comment: Thanks changing the Apostrophe ( ' ) to quotation marks worked ( " )

docker container commit --change="CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/mytroubleartifact-0.jar"]" xenodochial_goldwasser a-repo-name-of-choice/some-app-name:tagname2

Comment: Glad to hear it helped 